# How to find specific characters between two files?

Tags: cmd, find, character

I have two files `(file1, file2)` and I want to make a third one showing their differences using `cmd` like this:

```
file1 :qwertyuiop
file2 :qwartyuioa

file3:chr(3)=e a
      chr(10)=p a
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `fc %windir%\win.ini %windir%\system.ini`

Comment: `fc /b %windir%\win.ini %windir%\system.ini` A binary compare will list the value of each.

Comment: O.K. Thank you very much. It works fine with me, even on huge files (465 MB)  fc /b %windir%\win.ini %windir%\system.ini >>result.txt